# Jquery Remove() not removing selected node

Tags: jquery, append, file-management

I'm making a simple FileManager, but I don't know what is wrong with my code, I used several times the `remove()` and/or `detach()` functions of jQuery, but this time it isn't removing the selected node from the rest of the grid.

The code is the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".excluir").click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $("#novo").click(function(){
        $("#gradearquivos").append("<div class=\"miniatura\"><button class=\"excluir\">X</button></div>");
    });
});
</script>
```

The `append()` is working correctly, creating the file thumbs, but the `remove()` isn't!
What did I do wrong this time?
PS: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69RW2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) ,because the buttons are created dynamically.The elements are not present in the time of event binding. Also you need to select the `parent('.miniatura')` otherwise it will only remove the close icon not the `.miniatura` div

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gradearquivos").on('click',".excluir",function(){
        $(this).parent('.miniatura').remove();
    });

    $("#novo").click(function(){
        $("#gradearquivos").append("<div class=\"miniatura\"><button class=\"excluir\">X</button></div>");
    });
});
</script>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/69RW2/3/)

Comment: Yes otherwise you could just redo the binding when you append a new element.

Comment: @clancer : in that case each time need to bind event , I think this one is the best way

Answer (score 1):

You need **event delegation** using jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements. The elements having class `excluir` are added by javascript and are not present in DOM at the time click is binded. So the click event in not binded. You probably need to remove the parent element of button being clicked that is element with class `miniatura`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69RW2/2/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".excluir", function(){
    $(this).parent('.miniatura').remove();
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/).